# Make a row-wise Conditional Column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I got this dataframe:

```
Df = pd.DataFrame({'TIPOIDPRESTADOR': ['CC', 'NI', 'CE', 'RS'],
                                'Levels': [0, 1, np.nan, np.nan]
                      })


| TIPOIDPRESTADOR | Levels   |
| --------        | -------- |
| CC              | 0        |
| NI              | 1        |
| CE              | NaN      |
| RS              | NaN      |
```

and a want to make a loop that given the maximun value of the column 'Levels' (in this case 1) if the netx row is nan, then pass the maximun value of the column plus 1 and so on

the desired output should be something like this:

```
Desired_Output = pd.DataFrame({'TIPOIDPRESTADOR': ['CC', 'NI', 'CE', 'RS'],
                                'Levels': [0, 1, 2, 3]
                      })

| TIPOIDPRESTADOR | Levels   |
| --------        | -------- |
| CC              | 0        |
| NI              | 1        |
| CE              | 2        |
| RS              | 3        |
```

i was trying to use iterrows like this

```
for row in Df.iterrows():
    Max_value = float(max(Df[["TIPOIDPRESTADOR"]))
    Df['TIPOIDPRESTADOR'] = np.where(Df["TIPOIDPRESTADOR"].isna()==True, Max_value+1,  Df["TIPOIDPRESTADOR"])
    Max_value = Max_value+1
```

but i'm getting something like this:

```
| TIPOIDPRESTADOR | Levels   |
| --------        | -------- |
| CC              | 0        |
| NI              | 1        |
| CE              | 2        |
| RS              | 2        |
```

i know that it's a simple task but it's really struggling me

I would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were performing operations on `TIPOIDPRESTADOR` column rather than on `Levels` (assume those were typos, otherwise you wouldn't have got your result) and when using `np.where()` in a loop you probably have filled all `NaN` values in the first iteration and there has become nothing to update afterwards.

Try this:

```py
for i, row in Df.iterrows():
    if pd.isna(row['Levels']) == True:
        Df.loc[i, 'Levels'] = Df['Levels'].max() + 1 
    else:
        pass
Df
```

Output:

```
    TIPOIDPRESTADOR Levels
0   CC              0.0
1   NI              1.0
2   CE              2.0
3   RS              3.0
```